# Quiz Android Cronometro + Puntaje

Tags: android-studio

necestio desarrollar un Quiz en Android el esquema es el siguiente:
Cuatro pantallas en cada pantalla mostrar un cronometro y el puntaje al momento.
En cada pantalla una pregunta con cuatro posibles respuestas.

Si el cronometro termina entonces cambiar a la siguiente pantalla.
Si la respuesta en correcta sumar puntos, caso contrario 0;

La maquetación ya la tengo finalizada, he visto varios ejemplos pero en la mayoria usan Arreglos y/o listas. Lo que yo requiero es usar metdodos get y set y un If o Case para hacer la evaluación de la pantalla. La verdad tengo una ligera idea no encuentro como evaluar el timer y en como ir cambiando de pantalla en caso de que algunas de las acciones se cumpla fin del cronometro o contectación a la pregunta.

Para cambiar de pantalla estoy usando este codigo:

He agregado este codigo en la actividad de la pregunta 1, pero me esta sacando de la aplicación al dar clic en en la actividad que invoca dicha actividad (valda la redundancia)

```
    public class Ques1 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button r1,r2,r3,r4;
    TextView Tiempo,ocho,seis,cinco,diez;
//    LinearLayout layoutOcho,layoutSeis,layoutCinco,layoutDiez;
    private final int nextScreen=300;
    String valor="0";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ques1);

        r1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnResp1);
        r2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnResp2);
        r3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnResp3);
        r4=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnResp4);
        r1.setOnClickListener(this);
        r2.setOnClickListener(this);
        r3.setOnClickListener(this);
        r4.setOnClickListener(this);

        new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Tiempo.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                if(millisUntilFinished<6000){
//                    Tiempo.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorCrimson));
                    Tiempo.setBackgroundColor(000);
                }
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                if(ocho.getText()!="" && seis.getText()!="" && cinco.getText()!="" && diez.getText()!=""){
                    valor="0";
                    respuesta();
                    //finish();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnResp1:
//                layoutOcho.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorCrimson));
                ocho.setText("");
//                ocho.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_x_white));
                valor="0";
                respuesta();
                break;
            case R.id.btnResp2:
//                layoutSeis.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRoyalBlue));
                seis.setText("");
//                seis.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_check_white));
                valor="20";
                respuesta();
                break;
            case R.id.btnResp3:
//                layoutCinco.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorCrimson));
                cinco.setText("");
//                cinco.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_x_white));
                valor="0";
                respuesta();
                break;
            case R.id.btnResp4:
//                layoutDiez.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorCrimson));
                diez.setText("");
//                diez.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_x_white));
                valor="0";
                respuesta();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void respuesta(){
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent cambio = new Intent(Ques1.this,Ques2.class);
                String puntos = valor;
                cambio.putExtra("DATO",puntos);
                startActivity(cambio);
            }
        },nextScreen);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

    }
}
```

Y estoy tratando de armar un codigo para toda la app pero ando perdido, espero me puedan ayudar.

DS

Comment: Podes aclarar un poco donde estaria tu problema en particular?

Comment: @gbianchi
1. Claro, Estoy usando timer es correcto para lo que pretendo?
2. Tengo un Activity desde donde inicio y lanzo la pregunta 1
    aqui deberia de meter toda la funcion principal?
3. Para cambiar de pantalla al finalzar el timer o al dar push a un boton de 
    respuesta tengo que poner un on Clic (cambiar pantalla) a cada uno de ellos.

He buscado ejemplos para poder guiarme ya que soy nuevo an Android pero la mayoria de ellos son ejemplos avanzados usando Arreglos y/o listas, y solo tienen una pantalla es decir todas las preguntas la lanzan en esa misma actividad.